# Can't link headers to the program [OpenSSL]

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio, openssl

I'm using Visual Studio's Developer PowerShell to compile a cpp application that uses OpenSSL. But, every time I try to build the cpp file I get this error:

```
client.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: cannot open include file: 'openssl/ssl.h': No such file or directory
```

I'm using this command to build the code from the command console:

```powershell
cl /EHsc /I"INCLUDE" client.cpp /link /LIBPATH: "PATH" /OUT: client.exe
```

With `PATH` and `INCLUDE` are respectively the path to libraries of OpenSSL and the path to the headers.

So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are they the path to the headers or the path to the directory containing a directory named `openssl` that contains the headers?

Comment: "Can't link headers to the program" - of course you cannot link headers. Headers are not linked, they are `#include`'d in your source file. The linker links object files and libraries, not headers.

Comment: @RetiredNinja for both INCLUDEand PATH they are the path that leads to the libraries/headers. For example, the headers are in this path: "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl" and INCLUDE is set to this variable

Comment: The include you're having trouble with uses a relative path. You need to point to the directory that has the `openssl` directory in it. `"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include"`

Answer (score 0):

If header directory `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl` is set,
you need to use #include<ssl.h> in sclient.cpp.
Or as   Retired said, `"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include"`